# Tezos RPC doesn't respond with blocks below the current checkpoint

Tags: node, rpc

I've run my own instance of Tezos node and it seems that the node doesn't respond with blocks below the current checkpoint.

`GET /chains/main/checkpoint` response:

```
{
  "block": {
    "level": 212993,
    "proto": 3,
    "predecessor": "BLMXXvPj4rfPinsTcwgQkws5iqcqZKLnxCrSHXYErRk8Yt8s4ui",
    "timestamp": "2018-12-04T01:25:03Z",
    "validation_pass": 4,
    "operations_hash": "LLob1oFfM5pLnSH8vi9kM57JH9toqS9jR6XGkZt9gHeqzKiusBpge",
    "fitness": [
      "00",
      "000000000061a690"
    ],
    "context": "CoUu7Z1PCS3FoQqN96UAczb25S9c5HCtPsNbuQXdeT2CNqsssbaG",
    "protocol_data": "000100000003ddfe5afc00ed6f3c49c78ed62ff003b09b5af7db2b0479b79367cb60c2a1a85caeae20fca4da576f19ce9116a2cd6eafc1d737d032aa9ed1e3b292b57d378bd0ff90acf505"
  },
  "save_point": 212993,
  "caboose": 0,
  "history_mode": "full"
}
```

So, as we can see history_mode is "full". According to this article 
https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html
node with this mode stores all blocks.

But, 
`GET /chains/main/blocks/212992` response is 404 Not Found,
however,

`GET /chains/main/blocks/212992/header` response is a block header.

`GET /chains/main/blocks/212993` works properly and responses a block as it expected.

I used docker image to deploy the node.

**UPD**: `GET /chains/main/blocks/212992/operations` also doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

The blog post you referenced says that:

> A node running in `full`-mode stores the full chain data for all blocks, even the ones older than the current checkpoint. More precisely, it keeps the *headers* and the *operations* for these blocks. However, it discards the archived *context* and the operation and block *receipts*. We say that such a block information is “pruned”: we keep only the necessary bits that we got from the network, and drop everything that can be reconstructed from them.

So this explains why the `../<block_id>/header` endpoint works for you, while the “full information” endpoint probably requires some information that is pruned. However, this quote from the blog post implies that the `../<block_id>/operations` endpoint should work as well, and you should be able to reconstruct all the information you need from these two pieces of data (header and operations).

Comment: Unfortunately, `GET /chains/main/blocks/212993/operations` works as expected but `GET /chains/main/blocks/212992/operations` doesn't

Comment: The /operations RPC needs pruned info. A new RPC should be added for getting the raw operations data, without the receipts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with full-mode - please see [Full node unable to query operation data from blocks prior to most recent checkpoint](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/562) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

the issue has now been fixed in https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/1936.