# 404 error when calling some block ancestor

Tags: node, rpc, error

I am observing different behavior for some rpc call

```
curl -v http://mainnet.tezos.cryptium.ch:8732/chains/main/blocks/BKrq16vch5v3iEE1hHSMENLh54vBikkmqYLDv4j7hANx6ZE3Rmb~72755
```

gives me no data (error 404)

however when i do

```
curl -v https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/BKrq16vch5v3iEE1hHSMENLh54vBikkmqYLDv4j7hANx6ZE3Rmb~72755
```

I get the information about block `BLeam7Xqdw7w7ydU7g38gs82XJE6wNZMfm61cArUPaSFBzJ6q5r`. Why is that ?

Note that if i request a more recent offset like `~1` both return data for block `BLN3bh4ZCpBtade3VGbGbFWz2Nhvah3SqGKYZkdL6tbQ7FMD6f6`

EDIT: a related question regarding the nature of how full and archive nodes differ for this RPC call is available [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/tezos-rpc-doesnt-respond-with-blocks-below-the-current-checkpoint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the checkpoint rpc:

```
http://mainnet.tezos.cryptium.ch:8732/chains/main/checkpoint
```

which returns

```
{"block":
  {"level":729089,
   "proto":5,
   "predecessor":"BMF3ELahUsKsvSfct9qVFWX3Pf6aV2sLpKRgWkwTePpmo3tNjEG",
   "timestamp":"2019-12-09T21:56:50Z", "validation_pass":4,
   "operations_hash":"LLob8aa16cFyHG1rCrMQ2NrLDtCDegMNQLXmRWCHFD86KmYefbwbi",
   "fitness":["01","0000000000012001"], 
   "context":"CoWPc7UaEHYdXJ3PEpp6CyKB11K9XgX4n87cJpAMuFzbyAerrHSD",
   "protocol_data":  "0000756e6b6f8a3562bc00f131365318490b14b69329500a1f6e2000f0f767edf777ec9c6f33c6ff149eee289f642b2bdcbfdd8d54013da72eeedea56c1b828ba11c8adbd67f63f5e93578"},
 "save_point":729089,
 "caboose":0,
 "history_mode":"full"
}
```

history_mode for this node is "full" and full nodes prune data other than block's headers and operations from blocks before the current checkpoint.

Querying only the block's header in full mode works at any level, e.g.:
`curl -v http://mainnet.tezos.cryptium.ch:8732/chains/main/blocks/BKrq16vch5v3iEE1hHSMENLh54vBikkmqYLDv4j7hANx6ZE3Rmb~72755/header` works. Unfortunately, the RPC endpoint for block's operations in full mode is currently broken - [see issue "Full node unable to query operation data from blocks prior to most recent checkpoint"](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/562):

This is currently not shown for mainnet.smartpy.io (which is an archive node).

Edit: the rpc is now opened as well on mainnet.smartpy.io (and shows "archive").

````
{
  "block": {
    "level": 729089,
    "proto": 5,
    "predecessor": "BMF3ELahUsKsvSfct9qVFWX3Pf6aV2sLpKRgWkwTePpmo3tNjEG",
    "timestamp": "2019-12-09T21:56:50Z",
    "validation_pass": 4,
    "operations_hash": "LLob8aa16cFyHG1rCrMQ2NrLDtCDegMNQLXmRWCHFD86KmYefbwbi",
    "fitness": [
      "01",
      "0000000000012001"
    ],
    "context": "CoWPc7UaEHYdXJ3PEpp6CyKB11K9XgX4n87cJpAMuFzbyAerrHSD",
    "protocol_data": "0000756e6b6f8a3562bc00f131365318490b14b69329500a1f6e2000f0f767edf777ec9c6f33c6ff149eee289f642b2bdcbfdd8d54013da72eeedea56c1b828ba11c8adbd67f63f5e93578"
  },
  "save_point": 0,
  "caboose": 0,
  "history_mode": "archive"
}```
````

Comment: SmartPy node checkpoint : https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/checkpoint

Comment: @RoMarQ, I edited my answer to include the output of the checkpoint rpc on mainnet.smartpy.io.

Comment: Thanks! According to https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html the full set of operations are saved in full node. Does it mean offset is considered part of context ? EDIT: see https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/tezos-rpc-doesnt-respond-with-blocks-below-the-current-checkpoint for more details